# Passing variable between Ocaml modules

Tags: variables, ocaml

I am trying to pass an AST between modules, I wrote in the Main module the next sentence:

```
let var = "value" in
.
.
let tree = Parse.parse_tree ~file:input input_text |> M1.f1 |> M2.f2
```

The point is that in `M2.f2` I need to compute a function that receives a parameter from the `Main` module.
Is there a way to pass a parameter from one module to another? In a similar way as a "global variable", like in imperative programming? I read that I need to declare a signature in `Main.ml` in order to share data types or structures, but I was not able to understand how to use it to pass a variable between modules.
According to this example :
https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/modules.html
It is only necessary to reference the var using the name of the module dot the variable.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Why can you not just pass it as a function argument? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I am trying to use the variable "var" in M2.f2 using Main.var but "var" is only in the scope of Main and can not be recognized by M2.f2, the Main module is in another directory different from where M1 and M2 are placed.

Comment: I think I found the problem. I tried to use a variable declared in other module which is in the same directory and is working. The point with Main.ml is that it is stored in a different directory. Is possible to reference variables declared other modules in different directories?

Comment: This is a completely different question and it depends on the build system that you're using. On the lowest-level, when you use the `ocamlopt` or `ocamlc` compiler drivers, you can use the `-I` option to specify the directory in which modules will be searched. But usually you will be using some higher-level build configuration tool, like `dune` or `oasis`.

Comment: I am using "dune build" to compile the project

Comment: I updated my answer with dune instructions. But keep in mind, that circular dependencies are not allowed in OCaml, i.e., a library can't use the modules of your application.

Answer (score 2):

You can reference a value defined in another module using a qualified name that consists of the module name and the variable name. For example, to reference the variable `var` defined in module `Main`, you write, `Main.var`. Each compilation unit (file) in OCaml, implicitly defines a module with the same name as the file, except that it is capitalized and the extension is thrown away, e.g., if you have a file named `foo.ml` it will implicitly define a module `Foo` and to reference values defined in this module you need to prefix them with `Foo.`

By default, all values defined in a module are visible and can be referenced from other modules. You can hide values by defining a signature. If you have an implicit module defined by a file `foo.ml`, you can create a signature file `foo.mli` that will declare which values are visible.

When you have a complex [dune](https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) project with multiple folders, it is common that each subfolder defines a different library. Modules inside of the same library can reference each other directly by name. To reference a module in the other library, you should prefix the module name with the name of that library, e.g., `Mylib.Foo.var`. Look at the `dune` file in the folder that defines the library for the `name` field of the `library` definition, e.g.,

```
(library 
   (name mylib))
```

In order to access modules of the library `mylib` in some other library or program, you also need to add this library to the list of libraries. Open the `dune` file in your current folder, and find the corresponding `executable` or `library` definition and `(libraries mylib)` or append `mylib` if the `libraries` field already exists, e.g.,

```
(executable hello_word
  ...
  (libraries core mylib))
```

It is also important to know, that circular dependencies between modules are not permitted in OCaml. For example, if your main application is using library `mylib`, the library `mylib` can't reference the `main` module under any circumstances. So the only way to pass a value from the main module to the library is to pass it as an argument to a function.